# How to add Icons to Title bar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu, jmenubar

How do I add custom Icons to the Title bar as this person did?

[Jframe Title Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHmwy.png)

Comment: How about "don't do that"? Instead, leave the frame's taskbar as expected by the user and put the extra icons in a `JTaskBar` added to the top of the content pane of the frame (where the user ***would*** expect to see them).

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet displays an icon in the title bar:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Icons");
frame.setIconImages(icons);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setSize(200,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
```